# Cant get Php restrictions to work with HTML input tag for song upload

Tags: php, html

Hello I'm trying to get restrictions to work with my php upload script to make 
sure people are only uploading music nothing els but when I run in the browser 
I always get upload faild all post my code below

```
    <?php

    // This  PHP5 file is used to move an uploaded song file to its final
    // destination. The song is scaled as part of the process.

    // A normal HTML upload form will serve as the user interface  for the
    // upload.  The  song  file should be  submitted  using a  field named
    // "song". 

    // set database connection
    require("------.php");

    // lets get our posts //
       $song     = $_FILES['song'];
    // folder that will hold songs
       $songpath = "songs/";
    // song-file pathname
       $songpath .= $song["name"];

    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    //  this  file  is  going to add  restrictions to the song  form



       $ftype  = $_FILES["song"]["type"  ];
       $xerror = $_FILES["song"]["error" ];
       $xsize  = $_FILES["song"]["size"  ];

        if (($ftype == "audio/mp3"  )
         || ($ftype == "audio/ogg"  )
         || ($ftype == "audio/wav"  )
         || ($ftype == "audio/midi" ))

        {
            $it_is_a_song = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $it_is_a_song = 0;
        }

        if ($it_is_a_song && ($xsize < 20971520) && ($xerror == 0))
        {
            $it_is_good = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $it_is_good = 0;
        }



    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    print <<<END
    <html>
    <title>You Must Party Upload Results</title>
    <body>
    END;

    // move the file from the tmp folder to the song folder
    if ( $it_is_good &&
         move_uploaded_file ($song['tmp_name'], $songpath))
    {
         print "<p>Upload succeeded thank you</p>\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "<p>Upload failed, sorry</p>\n";
    }

    print <<<END
    <p>
    To continue, <a href="images.php">click here.</a>
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
    END;

    ?>
```

Comment: As a heads-up: checking the browser-supplied MIME type is not 100% safe - there can be false negatives, and an attacker can fake the MIME type while uploading a file that is not a music file.

Comment: I'm still pretty new to Php is there a way around the browser MIME type ? that does concern me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_FILES["song"]["type"]` will return mime type and `song` mime type doesn't exist so it'll always fail.

Instead use `audio`, eg. `audio/ogg`.

Comment: Would there be any way to specify what you mean iv change the code to audio/mp3 audio/ogg but still get the upload faild iv done some googling but really cant find any thing

Comment: @user2976573 Try to debug your script. The easiest way to do it is putting `var_dump()` and `die()` to show values of some variables and stop script execution. In this case you want to know what is in `$ftype` just before `if` statement. If value is correct, then check variables `$xerror` and `$xsize`. It's possible that everything is ok here. If so, check what will `move_uploaded_file()` return. One of this will lead you to solution.

Comment: Got the script working debug it and found that the audio/mp3 had to be the mime type so it was audio/mpeg and audio/x-wav insted of audio/wav i need to learn more about mime type but least its working